# Pip installs to wrong folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I just reinstalled Python to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Programming Languages\Phyton

if I now install something, e.g.: `pip install pygame`, it installs it to
C:\Users\Gereon\AppData\Roaming\Python
and I found folders there I don't want there. I also want to install pip packages to a location where I'll find it quicker, like before: `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Programming Languages\\Phyton\\lib\\site-packages`

I already tried some things and found the command: `python -m site. I got the following:

```
sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\Gereon',
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Programming Languages\\Phyton\\python38.zip',
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Programming Languages\\Phyton\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Programming Languages\\Phyton\\lib',
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Programming Languages\\Phyton',
    'C:\\Users\\Gereon\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Programming Languages\\Phyton\\lib\\site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: 'C:\\Users\\Gereon\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python' (exists)
USER_SITE: 'C:\\Users\\Gereon\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Now obviously I see a correlation, but I'm unable to find any solutions, that satify my needs.

PS: `pip install --target="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Programming Languages\\Phyton\\lib\\site-packages" pygame` is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: having Python installed on the C partition of Windows (e.g. C:\\Program Files (x86)) will require elevated rights for pip installations - which you seem to not having given to it (start cmd as admin and try again). But why not save yourself the trouble and have a 'normal' user installation of Python, by default to C:\\Users\\Gereon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs? then you can call pip normally and you'll find installed packages in that directory

Comment: Who's to say `AppData\Roaming\Python` is "wrong"? If anything seems the problem is around that USER_SITE variable and it being enabled

Comment: @MrFuppes Even running as admin did not help me solve the issue. It is still is installing in \AppData\Roaming\Python. Any other solutions to work around?

Comment: @Priya: that strongly depends on your *specific* setup (also check how your `PATH` env variable is configured, do you e.g. have different paths specified for Admin and User?). In general, I can  only recommend using a User-Installation of Python, not a System-Installation (this applies to Windows *and* Unix btw.).

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks. Somehow after I uninstalled, reinstalled and reset the path, it worked now. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MrFuppes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10197418/mrfuppes) helped me a lot: I just had to run the CMD as admin

Comment: Generally speaking, packages shouldn't be installed globally, and you'd make a virtualenv per project

Comment: If you're just starting out with Python, don't worry too much about messing up the installation. Once you get the hang of it, you can have a look at virtual environments, package management etc. For Windows, there's e.g. [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win). I like that in combination with [poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry) - but that's just an option, there's more out there  ;-)